# Broadcastreceiver onreceive not called

Tags: android

I am sending a broadcast from one of my classes:

```
    // Sending broadcast from my db helper constructor
    public DBHelper(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("custom.alert.abc");
    intent.putExtra("key",77);ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);




    //registering the broadcast in one of my activities oncreate
     IntentFilter alaramfilter = new IntentFilter();
    alaramfilter.addAction("custom.alert.abc");
     registerReceiver(alarmreceiver, alaramfilter); 

    //and declaring it
    private final BroadcastReceiver alarmreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Broadcast received inside on receive");
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals("custom.alert.abc")) {
        Log.d("CPSnippetMain","My custom broadcast called");
        try {
             System.out.println("Broadcast received");
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
};
```

The problem is, though the constructor is called, and broadcast is sent, onreceive is not called.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: yes, edited my question. I missed to include it

Comment: sorry, missed again.. added now

Comment: by any chance, are these in the order that you have put above, sendbroadcast and then register?

Comment: can you please post that as an answer. I will accept it ;) . Isee that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which you `sendbroadcast` and `register` is important.
First register and then do a sendBroadcast.

Answer (score 0):

Register the boardcast

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver_;

@Overrride
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){



 IntentFilter filter_data = new IntentFilter();
 filter_data .addAction("SOME_ACTION");


 receiver_= new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  //do something based on the intent's action
}
 }

 registerReceiver(receiver_, filter_data );
```

and unregisterReceiver in on destroy methord

> unregisterReceiver(receiver_);